# iOS 9 Failed Connection to REST Web Service

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, nsurlconnection

I'm a bit new to developing iOS applications, and one of the things I need to do in this app is connected to a REST Web Service. I have tested the WS in the Postman Extension and everything works fine, but I can't seem to do the same through the iOS application. This is the code that I use to try and establish the connection:

```
NSString *wsAuth = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic \%@", [[@"USER:PASS" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] base64EncodedStringWithOptions:nil]];
NSMutableDictionary *post = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[post setValue:login forKey:@"user"];
[post setValue:pass forKey:@"pass"];
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:post, nil];
NSData *jsonPost = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arr options:0 error:nil];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://mywebservice.mywebsite.com/auth/"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonPost];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [jsonPost length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:wsAuth forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[conn start];

NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

if([response statusCode] >=200 && [response statusCode] <300) {
    // Process data...
}
else {
    // Present error...
}
```

I received the following errors from Xcode:

```
2016-03-16 11:02:34.658 [31742:2969162] Response = (null)

2016-03-16 11:02:34.659 [31742:2969162] Error =
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out."
UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://mywebservice.mywebsite.com/auth/,
_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102,
NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://mywebservice.mywebsite.com/auth/,
NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.,
_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4,
NSUnderlyingError=0x7aa5b510 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "The request timed out."
UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102,
NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://mywebservice.mywebsite.com/auth/, 
NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://mywebservice.mywebsite.com/auth/,
NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.,
_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}}

2016-03-16 11:02:34.693 [31742:2969383] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)
2016-03-16 11:02:34.799 [31742:2969383] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9802)
2016-03-16 11:02:34.889 [31742:2969383] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9802)
2016-03-16 11:02:34.890 [31742:2969383] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
```

A couple extra things to know. I am programming this as an iOS 9 application that needs to work with iOS 8 or newer, and I am doing this in Xcode 7. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try searching on those errors? [error -9806](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+CFNetwork+SSLHandshake+failed+%27-9806%27) and [error -9802](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+CFNetwork+SSLHandshake+failed+%27-9802%27).

Comment: Yes I have, and I know for a fact that the certificate is legitimate and up to date TLS v1.2., and I have verified that the app connects to the internet.  I have tried applying updates to my plist and that still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you added NSAppTransportSecurity key in info plist file ?

Comment: Yes, and that didn't work either. I have tried Allowing Arbitrary Loads, as well as putting in rules specific to my domain. There aren't any issues with security here. The web service is behind a valid and up-to-date certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I figured this out on my own. I guess making a synchronous request did not work, so I switched to asynchronous. This gave me a more accurate error which showed me that instead of passing a JSON object, I was passing an array with the first and only entry was a JSON object, which was causing the authentication to fail.

Just to clarify, this solution contains several objects to communicate with the RESTful web service. This is done through a POST, using a JSON object as the POST variables. This web service requires Basic Authentication, which is achieved through this code at Lines 1 and 15. Finally, this is all based on a web service that is behind a secure connection and an up-to-date SSL certificate. I'm not 100% sure what the work around would be for an HTTP request, or a self-signed certificate...

Side note: I removed the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` key and the `NSAppTransportSecurity` dictionary from my `info.plist` file and this solution still worked.

Here is the code that provided me with a successful connection to my secure Web Service:

```
NSString *wsAuth = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic \%@", [[@"USER:PASS" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]];
NSMutableDictionary *post = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[post setValue:login forKey:@"user"];
[post setValue:pass forKey:@"pass"];
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:post, nil];
// Note the first value of the array is being referenced, not the entire array.
NSData *jsonPost = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arr[0] options:0 error:nil];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://mywebservice.mywebsite.com/auth/"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonPost];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [jsonPost length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:wsAuth forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if ([data length] >0 && error == nil) {
        // Process data here...
    }
    else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Empty Response. Check your credentials.");
    }
    else if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error = %@", error);
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add just the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` key to `YES` in `NSAppTransportSecurity` dictionary in your `info.plist` file.

[image]